# CsvHelper to save derived class object from abstract class

Tags: c#, csvhelper

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class AbstractModel : ObservableObject
{
    // nothing.
}

public class RealModel : AbstractModel 
{
    public string PropertyA {get; set;}
    public string PropertyB {get; set;}
}
```

Note that `ObservableObject` is from Mvvm-light.

With above models, I used [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) as below.

```
AbstractModel instance = new RealModel()
                             {
                                 PropertyA = "foo",
                                 PropertyA = "bar"
                             };

using (TextWriter file = new StreamWriter("path"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(file))
{
    csv.WriteRecord(instance);
}
```

It throws error as below;

> No properties are mapped for type 'AbstractModel'

It works fine when I set `RealModel instance = new RealModel();` instead. But, I have various derived classes and want to save them in a single Save method.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is three years old, but I was attempting to do the same thing, and I've found a hack to get it to work.

The offending code in csvHelper is the following:

```
public virtual Type GetTypeForRecord<T>(T record)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    if (type == typeof(object))
    {
        type = record.GetType();
    }

    return type;
}
```

The C# generic that is passed down to this method is determined at compile time, so T is always going to be the base class, not the derived class, but if you cast to to type `object` before calling `WriteRecord`, the method will use `GetType()`, which will return the derived type.

```
AbstractModel instance = new RealModel()
                             {
                                 PropertyA = "foo",
                                 PropertyA = "bar"
                             };

using (TextWriter file = new StreamWriter("path"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(file))
{
    csv.WriteRecord((object)instance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I would say, this is the way it is supposed to be.
The output is not an XML file, but a CSV file. And CSV file has only a single header (when it has any; not all CSV files have a header).

The parser can not determine class by data in line.

Standard CSV data example 1 (names):

```
ID,GivenName,FamilyName
1,John,A
2,Mike,B
```

Standard CSV data example 2 ("anniversaries"):

```
Date,Anniversary
1.1.,New year
```

When you save to CSV file, you can not have two "header lines"; how should the parser know, to which child class decode the output? Names or anniversaries? Why is the first line "name" and the second "anniversary"? Why is it not another way around?

This approach is not good. At least not for a CSV file. There should be always a table with exact count of column for each line.
When the count of data is always exact, you can me converters from your class to a universal class and from universal class to specific data classes (for parser).

Non standard data example: (names and anniversaries; no header line):

```
1,John,A
1.1.,New year
2,Mike,B
```

Try to ask your self, how should the parser handle this file? Yes the data are stored in "the CSV way", but I don't think, these data are correct. This is not the way it should be.

I know there are situations, when you need to use this approach (formatted data; first item specify type, all other values in line are data for given type). But for this usage you need to make a different approach to store and parse the data.

A example of different approach:

```
public abstract class AbstractModel : ObservableObject
{
    // no property

    protected string Prefix(object data)
    {
       if (ReferenceEquals(data, null))
         return string.Empty;
       string result = data.ToString();
       if (data.Contains(",") || data.Contains("\""))
         return $"\"{data}\"";
       return data;
    }

}

public class RealModel : AbstractModel 
{
    public string PropertyA {get; set;}
    public string PropertyB {get; set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return $"{Prefix(PropertyA)},{Prefix(PropertyB)}";
    }
}
```

And save with:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("path"))
{
  foreach (AbstractModel instance in allInstances)
    file.WriteLine(instance);
}
```

Comment: But I intended to save single object to single file, so header is not varied. maybe it's by-design?

Comment: got it. I see what you are saying.